# How to Make A ListView Checkbox React like Radio Button

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox, radio-button

I have several items in my listview which are checkboxes.

I managed to use this code in my listview "ItemChecked" event:

```
For Each item In lwSources.Items
    If Not item.Index = e.Item.Index Then item.Checked = False
Next
```

---

The problem is that it isn't reacting correctly. For example, if none are selected, I click once and the item gets selected correctly. If I try to click on another item (that isn't checked), then the first one I checked gets unchecked, and I must click again to check the one I currently want.

It requires 1 more click than needed...

Comment: can you explain where you are loading/binding  your listbox?? because here you are checking for all items in listbox,so when you check for second item it will loop again with all items,means the index of second time checked item is different then first already checked item,so condition is ture so previous checked item is set to unchecked and second item is checked....

Comment: lwSources listview is filled with the items selected from another dialog box. Based on my selection, those selected items will be added to lwSources

Comment: its just matter of you are looping through all items in listbox

Comment: Do you want the previous checkbox still to be checked or not?

Comment: Nope, I don't want the previous checkbox to still be checked. I'd like the checkboxes to react like radio buttons (since radio buttons cannot be put in a listview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an hour of trying I have finally done it.

Firstly set a global variable like so..

```
Dim a As Integer = 0
```

Within the normal click event set it to 0, which will be fired first.

```
    Private Sub ListView1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles   ListView1.Click
     a = 0
    End Sub
```

And in the listview item checked, check that a = 0.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked

    If a = 0 Then
        For Each item In lwSources.Items
            a = 1
            If Not item.Index = e.Item.Index Then
                item.Checked = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I think the problem is that when we are changing the checked value, it is firing the event again but with no sender, which is why they all go to a state of unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

in this condition set this condition and try....

```
For Each item In lwSources.Items
      If  item.Index = e.Item.Index Then
       item.Checked = true
      End If
 Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately all of the checkboxes get checked.

Comment: you are using checkbox inside listbox ya?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I figured only an "else" with an item.checked = false would suffice. But I end up with a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you over there your code is great and it will also work great if you place your code in ItemCheck event instead of ItemChecked event like this

`Private Sub IMFavIconList_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles IMFavIconList.ItemCheck
            For Each item In sender.Items
                If Not item.Index = e.Index Then item.Checked = False
            Next
        End Sub`

It works great for me buddy!